# Error when counting group by columns in Python-TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the duplicate rows per hour.

My data frame:

```
 hour         index    name    
08:00:00      1442       x
08:45:00      3434       y
08:30:00      1442       x
08:00:00      1442       x
08:45:00      3434       y
08:00:00      1442       x
```

My code: I tried to group the data per hour and count. transform didn't help.

```
df_count= df.groupby('hour')[['index','name']].count()
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

This is the output I want:

```
 hour         index    name   count  
08:00:00      1442       x       3
08:30:00      1442       x       1
08:45:00      3434       y       2
```

Comment: To get the number of elements in each group, just use df.groupby("hour").size()

Comment: @tanglef  It's not working. I get the same error. But I want the distinct on all the row not just the hour. I added he output I'm looking for to the question.

Comment: Allright, then to groupby multiple columns, you can give the list of the columns names in groupby.

Comment: @tanglef same error- this is what I tried to run df_count= df.groupby(['hour', 'index','name']).size()

Comment: what is the dtype of your columns? can you paste code to rebuild your exact dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on with your data. When I set one up like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'hour': ['08:00:00', '08:45:00', '08:30:00', '08:00:00', '08:45:00', '08:00:00'],
    'index': [1442, 3434, 1442, 1442, 3434, 1442],
    'name': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'x'],
})
```

Then your code works fine (it doesn't do what you want, but it runs without issues):

```py
>>> df.groupby('hour')[['index','name']].count()
          index  name
hour                 
08:00:00      3     3
08:30:00      1     1
08:45:00      2     2
```

In any case, once you fix your DataFrame content, the following should get the expected result:

```py
>>> df.groupby(['hour', 'index', 'name']).size()
hour      index  name
08:00:00  1442   x       3
08:30:00  1442   x       1
08:45:00  3434   y       2
```

You can also add: `.to_frame('count').reset_index()` if you like.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the problem with the column's type and your code works.